# SharePoint Designer - not able to edit page layout in advanced mode

Tags: sharepoint-designer

SharePoint Designer was giving me a popup to tell me I could edit the page in advanced mode. This has stopped happening and now I just get a page with yellow background.

How can I edit the page layout in advanced mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the ribbon and click Advanced Mode.

More info in this article - http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/cizi/archive/2010/08/15/editing-page-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-with-yellow-marked-code-advance-mode.aspx

*In answer to @Havoc*

If advanced mode not available it may be due to a setting in Central Admin
[From this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Managing-SharePoint-Designer-2010-e12d76ce-83f7-4dde-864c-6c1e210399b6?CorrelationId=4062095f-bbb7-4e94-993b-7ac93aadc835&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> Central Administration
>
> Use the SharePoint Designer Settings page in Central Administration to
>   manage SharePoint Designer at the web application level, which
>   includes all site collections in the web application. These settings
>   apply to site collection administrators and all users of the web
>   application.

Enable Detaching Pages from the Site Definition

> Enables or disables the ability to detach pages from the site
>   definition. If unchecked, SharePoint Designer only allows you to edit
>   pages in normal mode. The Edit File in Advanced Mode is disabled. 
>   Note This setting does not apply to pages that have already been
>   detached as well as new blank ASPX or HTML pages created by the user.

Comment: What happens if "Advanced Mode" is grayed out?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate Paul Rowland's solution
 1. Open https://youraccount.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx
[image]

2. Then turn on [Enable Detaching Pages from the Site Definition] as above picture shows.
3. Then open your team site: like

https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/teams/Marketing/_layouts/15/settings.aspx

4. Open sharepoint designer settings[image]
5. Then repeat turning on

   -Enable SharePoint Designer 
   -Enable Detaching Pages from the Site Definition 
   [image]