# "Parse HTML" button missing in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to follow along with [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191894/how-to-group-by-more-than-2-columns-in-sharepoint-2013) to Group By more than 2 levels in a View. The problem is, every tutorial starts with "Click Parse HTML" under Code Editor. I don't have a "Parse HTML" button, as you can see here:

[image]

I've gone through all the Ribbon settings and it's just not there. Is there a setting I'm not familiar with causing it to be hidden? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: May be helpful [link](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple reasons why this is happening. Refer to this post for enabling Advanced Editing.

[image]

[SharePoint Designer - not able to edit page layout in advanced mode](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/sharepoint-designer-not-able-to-edit-page-layout-in-advanced-mode)

Comment: Checked this out, all the options under SharePoint Designer Settings are checked.